# h:commanLink onclick confirmation not working

Tags: java, jsf-2

Am using h:commandLink for delete,onclick of this link which enables the confirm dialog but when i click ok,it is not deleting..do i need to add any more?kindly help.

```
<h:commandLink  update="#{cc.attrs.ajaxupdate}" 
onclick="if (! confirm('Are you sure, you want to remove picture?') ) { return 
false;};     return true; ">
<f:ajax listener="#{cc.attrs.deleteactionlistener}"/>
<p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/delete.gif" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: how about you move all code to a java script method?

Comment: Just i got a example from Net.How to do this?

Comment: @Karthik : see my answer. It will work.

Comment: Please elaborate "not working" in developer's terms instead of in enduser's terms. Is the HTTP request fired? Is the HTTP request retrieved? Is the bean constructed? Is the method invoked? Is the HTTP response sent? Is the HTTP response retrieved? Is the desired ajax update present in the HTTP response? Is the ajax update properly performed on HTML DOM tree? The way how you put your question suggests that the method is not invoked, but based on your code it could also be as good possible that it is definitely invoked, but the desired update isn't performed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the `h:commandLink` within an `h:form` element in order to submit your data and execute the handler. The `onclick` on the other hand is done without a submit.

By the way, what is the `update` attribute for? At least it's not in the standard `h:commandLink`.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your response.Its inside the h:form.This is done with composite component..the update attribute refers to form.

Comment: Geziefer means that the `<h:commandLink>` doesn't support the `update` attribute at all. Perhaps you're confusing with `<p:commandLink>` which has indeed that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Below is how I used...

```
<h:commandLink value="Delete" action="#{Bean.delete()}" 
    onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" />
             ^^^^^^^
```

In your case it would be

```
<h:commandLink  update="#{cc.attrs.ajaxupdate}" 
     onclick="return confirm('Are you sure, you want to remove picture?')">
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: OP's approach is indeed overly clumsy (classic example of a starter who doesn't firmly grasp boolean logic in code), but it does effectively exactly the same.